# Java application on Network share stops working after Windows Energy Saving

Tags: java, windows, networking

Hi Everybody we have a Problem with one of our java applications(based on Netbeans RCP) which is deployed on a network share which is mapped on all our PCs. It worked this way for several years.

Since we migrated to Windows 10 we see this application failing after Windows returns from Energy Saving Mode. We found the reason in Windows shutting down the network-card. The JVM seems unable to handle this connection loss.

I know that you can tell Windows to keep the network online but our Admins dont like this solution. We developers dont like to have it deployed localy.

So my Question is if it is possible for Java to handle this temporary disconnect. Maybe there is a JVM-Param or even some things we can do in code.

I am no english native so sry if something isn't understandable.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess the connection loss results in an exception? You can catch it and entere a program part, where it does nothing than checking for reconnection.

Comment: Yes it results in an exception but its entirely in Java or Platform-Code. I find none of our classes in the stacktrace